Error when importing RPi.GPIO - Micropython - Raspberry pi pico
I'm trying to import RPI.GPio into the program below and I encounter the following error, on the first line: MPY: soft reboot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: no module named 'RPi'

Obs.: I'm using Thonny, the settings in tools options and interpreter are already for Micropython
Codigo:
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import hx711

# Configuração de GPIOs
dt_pin = 17
clk_pin = 18

# Configuração do HX711
hx = hx711.HX711(dt_pin, clk_pin)

# Calibração (ajuste os valores conforme necessário)
SCALE = 318.64  # Fator de escala
OFFSET = 117800  # Offset

hx.set_scale(SCALE)
hx.set_offset(OFFSET)

# Função para ler o peso
def read_weight():
    try:
        # Leia o valor bruto do HX711
        weight_raw = hx.get_raw_data()
        if weight_raw is None:
            raise ValueError("Falha ao obter dados brutos do sensor")

        # Converta o valor bruto em peso
        weight = hx.get_weight(scale=SCALE, offset=OFFSET)

        # Imprima o valor do peso
        print(f"Peso: {weight:.2f} kg")
        return weight

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Erro ao ler peso: {e}")
        return None

def main():
    try:
        while True:
            read_weight()
            time.sleep(1)  # Ajuste o tempo de intervalo entre as leituras

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Encerrando o programa...")
    finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()
        print("GPIO limpo.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


I would like to read the data from this load cell.I would like to read the data from this load cell.
I would like to read the data from this load cell.

RPi.GPIO is for the full-featured Raspberry Pi models running Linux - it is simply not applicable to the Pico.  MicroPython supplies its own module for controlling GPIO pins, named machine - you will need to rewrite your code to use that module.
